# Centroid of matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, centroid

Given a 2D array, I am required to come up with an algorithm which outputs the center of mass. I came up with algorithm below, however, it is producing incorrect solution when the array size is increased to 10 x 10 matrix. I wrote and ran the algorithm using java. I have not provided the codes here, but just an explanation of my algorithm as i feel that it is not right. However, I am unable to find out why.

```
Store into an array: Mean of each row
Store into an array: Mean of each column

The algo below is used for row and column:
Loop through the row array,
if(row = 1){
value = (mean of row 1) - (mean of row 2 + mean of row 3+ mean of row 4)
}else if(row =Length of array){
value = (mean of row 1 + mean of row 2 + mean of row 3) - (mean of row 4)}
else{
value = (mean of rows until ith row) - (ith row till end of array)
}
final value = lowest value;
```

I know that it is supposed to deal with mean of the rows and columns. So in my algorithm, i find out the means of rows and columns and then conduct the calculation shown above. The same algo applies to the columns.

Any and all help is appreciated. Maybe, my understanding of center of mass is incorrect. If something is not clear, then do ask. This is my own algorithm, created from my understanding of center of mass, so if its not clear, please do ask. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass I'd say if you treat the cells as particles laid out in equal distance on a 2d plane you should be able to adapt the corresponding equation.

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't mention distance, which is pivotal (pun intended).

Comment: @Thomas, Cells meaning each of the individual values in the 2d array?  And use the equation found under system of particles, and substitute the m with the values found in the 2d array and R is not included as the distance is equal? Thank you.

Comment: Yes cells means the individual values, position would be defined by the column and row indices.

Comment: @weston Hmmm..i looked the formula given, but am not sure on what value to add as a distance, as this is a 2D array with values ranging from 0-1.

Comment: Which formula given?

Comment: @weston In the wikipedia link given by Thomas, under the section system of particles. I can't seem to copy and paste it here.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below. `r(i)` would be the position in the matrix as defined by column and row index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you should be able calculate the center of mass as follows:

```
foreach col 
  foreach row
    massvector.x += matrix[col][row] * col
    massvector.y += matrix[col][row] * row
    totalmass += matrix[col][row]
massvector.x /= totalmass    
massvector.y /= totalmass
```

The idea is based on the section "A system of particles" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass: treat the matrix elements as equally spaced particles laid out on a 2D plane. The position of each element is equal to its position within the matrix, i.e. column and row, while the particle mass is the value of that cell/element/matrix position.

Example-Implementation using your (now deleted) test case:

```
double[][] matrix = new double[][]{
    {0.70,0.75,0.70,0.75,0.80},
    {0.55,0.30,0.20,0.10,0.70},
    {0.80,0.10,0.00,0.00,0.80},
    {0.70,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.80},
    {0.80,0.90,0.80,0.75,0.90}};

double cx = 0;
double cy = 0;
double m = 0;

for(int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++ ) {
  for(int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++) {
    cx += matrix[x][y] * x;
    cy += matrix[x][y] * y;
    m += matrix[x][y];
  }
}

//those are center's the cell coordinates within the matrix
int cmx = (int)(cx/m); 
int cmy = (int)(cy/m);

//whatever you'd need that value for (the position is more likely what you're after)
double centerOfMassValue = matrix[cmx][cmy];
```

The example above would return coordinates 2/2 with is the center of the 5x5 matrix.

Comment: Although `centerOfMassValue` is of questionable use.  But +1 for everything else.

Comment: @Teepeemm I just added `centerOfMassValue` because he was referring to the value in the original version of the question. It's probably not of much use besides that :)

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you very much Thomas. I seemed to have understood and implemented the algorithm incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a weighted average so for an 3x3 array,

x̄= (mass(col1)*1 + mass(col2)*2 + mass(col3)*3) / (mass(col1) + mass(col2) + mass(col3))

and similarly for y replacing columns with rows.

Once you have those two values, the pair of them will tell you the x and y coordinates of the center of mass for your array.

See example one in the following link if you need a visual example: http://www.batesville.k12.in.us/physics/APPhyNet/Dynamics/Center%20of%20Mass/2D_1.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that since you are storing the weights in a matrix, that the position in the matrix will correspond with the coordinates of the weight where the column index is *x* row index is *y*.  Thus a weight at row=2,col=3 we will take to be (3,2) on the x/y coordinate system.

This code follows the [solution for center of mass from a system of particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#A_system_of_particles) on Wikipedia:

```
public static Point2D.Double getCenterOfMass( double[][] matrix) {
    double massTotal = 0;
    double xTotal = 0;
    double yTotal = 0;
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < matrix.length; rowIndex++) {
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < matrix[0].length; colIndex++) {
            massTotal += matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];
            xTotal += matrix[rowIndex][colIndex] * colIndex;
            yTotal += matrix[rowIndex][colIndex] * rowIndex;
        }
    }
    xTotal /= massTotal;
    yTotal /= massTotal;
    return new Point2D.Double(xTotal,yTotal);
}
```

Full working code [here](https://repl.it/BxRM/0).